# How to read a specific line and text from a text file

Tags: c#, regex

```
string lot = "RU644276G01";

var year = "201" + lot.Substring(2, 1);
var folder = @"\\sinsdn38.ap.infineon.com\ArchView\03_Reports\" + year +
             @"\" + lot.Substring(3, 2) + @"\" + lot.Substring(0,8) + @"\";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);

foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*.TLT"))
{
    var file = fi.FullName;
    string line;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("TEST-END"))
            {
                timeStampTextBox.Text = line;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code currently.

I want to read from a specific line (for example line 8) and the line starts with `"Test-End"`. However, line 8 contains all these

> `"TEST-END : 2017-01-08 15:51   PROGRAM  : TLE8888QK-B2       BAU-NR    : 95187193"`

but I **only want to read `"2017-01-98 15:51"`**.

How do I change my code to get that? Currently I'm getting the whole line instead of the specific timestamp that I want.

*Edit* 
How do I change the code such that the `string lot ="       "` can be any number, meaning it does not need to be RU644276G01, it can be a different number which will be typed by users. I have created a textbox for users to input the number.

Comment: If you already got the line, try fiddling with [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You extract the text. It seems quite regular pattern, so regular expressions should be able to help:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = "TEST-END : 2017-01-08 15:51 PROGRAM : TLE8888QK-B2 BAU-NR : 95187193";

        Regex re = new Regex(@"^(?:TEST-END : )(.*?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})");

        var match = re.Match(line);

        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);         

        Console.ReadLine(); // leave console open
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2017-01-08 15:51   // this is group 1, group 0 is the full capture including TEST-END :
```

Use this to check it in regexr:  https://regexr.com/3l1sf  if you hover about the text it will diplay your capturing groups

The regex means:

```
^                                    start of the string
 (?:TEST-END : )                     non capturing group, text must be present
 (                                   a group
   .*?                               as few (0-n) anythings as possible
   \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}     4 digits-2 digits-2digits 2digits:2digits
 )                                   end of group
```

More about regular expressions:

- [RegEx-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)
- a regex Tester (one of many, the one I use): https://regexr.com/

Comment: Nice, but I think OP wants the output to be without "TEST-END : "

Comment: @Neijwiert thanks for the catch, fixed it and put it in regexr to play around with

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insights on Regular Expressions! May I ask also, where do I put in the codes? Do I put the codes into "program.cs" or into the one that I typed all my codes in?

Comment: @Crystal Well we assumed that you already know a way to get the line you desire, then this should be placed after the logic you used to get that line.

Comment: @Crystal I would probably create a method that takes in a string (your line) and spits out the part you want or an empty string if thats not present. You could also go for a `bool TryParse(string line, out  string timeStamp)` method mimicing the `TryParse(..)` thats provided on most basic types (bool, int, ...) so you can put it into your code as `string myDate; if (TryParse(myLine, out myDate)) { .... do smth with myDate ..} else ....`

Answer (score 0):

you can split the line with ":",  like this

```
 var value = line.split(':');
```

and get your date like this.

```
 var date = value[1] + ":" + value[2].Replace("PROGRAM", "");
```

above statement means

```
date = "2017-01-98 15" + ":" + "51"

                if (line.StartsWith("TEST-END"))
                {
                    var value = line.split(':');
                    var date = value[1] + ":" + value[2].Replace("PROGRAM", "");
                    timeStampTextBox.Text = date;
                }
```

This is not the best answer, it depends on exactly the statement you had given.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer! May I ask, where do I put this code in? after the "if" or inside the "if" command?

Comment: Wont work. if you split at `:` the  `value[2]` will look like `"51 PROGRAM "`

Comment: I would not recommend to do this without Regex, they are specifically designed for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer using Regular Expressions.

```
if (line.StartsWith("TEST-END"))
{
    Regex re = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}");
    var match = re.Match(line);

    if(m.Success)
    {
        timeStampTextBox.Text = match.Value;
    }
}
```

Output: 2017-01-08 15:51

Answer (score 0):

I finally got all three parameters out of the last line

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^\s]+)\s:\s(?'value'[\w\s\-]*|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2})";
            string line = "TEST-END : 2017-01-08 15:51 PROGRAM : TLE8888QK-B2 BAU-NR : 95187193";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("name : '{0}', value : '{1}'", match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
                dict.Add(match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }

            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dict["TEST-END"]);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```